# Multidimensional array get value from parent array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a nested array of my sites pages. I already have a recursive array to nest the structure based on parent id. I want to add a key to each subsequent array that is the url for the page. The url will be built dynamically off of segments.

My array of pages looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Homepage
            [url_title] => homepage
            [parent] => 
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => About
                            [url_title] => about
                            [parent] => 1
                            [pages] => 
                            [_id] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Blog
                            [url_title] => blog
                            [parent] => 1
                            [pages] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [title] => Archives
                                            [url_title] => archives
                                            [parent] => 3
                                            [pages] => 
                                            [_id] => 4
                                        )

                                )

                            [_id] => 3
                        )

                )

            [_id] => 1
        )

)
```

I was able to write another recursive function that looped through the array and created another array of routes like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => '/homepage',
    [2] => '/homepage/about',
    [3] => '/homepage/blog',
    [4] => '/homepage/blog/archives',
)
```

For my templating engine though I would like to have those values be included with the nested array instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - SO is a question and answer site, and we expect that you have written some code and need help with a specific problem

Comment: You want to see the functions I use to generate this?

Comment: Yes, please edit the question to show your code. The way SO works is that you make the first effort, and we can help with problems, we won't write code from scratch for you